# Select & deselecting list items with one button

Tags: android, listview

I need to have a button to select all list items when no item is selected,and this button should deselect all the items that allready selected,i mean a button that do two task!1-select all list items,2-deselect all list items,how i should implement that?, Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

I change my code to the below,but only select all working!
checkselectedItems checked if all items selected or not:

```
               public boolean checkSelectedItems(){

                for (int k=0;k<listView.getCount();++k){
                    if(listView.isItemChecked(k)==true)
                   return true;
                }

                return false;

           }
```

and for my button:

```
                         case R.id.select_all:
                         Log.i(TAG, "selectAllEntries");


                         for (int i = 0; i < listView.getCount(); ++i) {
                             if (checkSelectedItems()){

                             listView.setItemChecked(i, false);}
                             listView.setItemChecked(i, true);


                         }
```

Comment: Add a header view to your `ListView` with a `CheckBox` to select all/none?

Comment: @darnmason: nope,when I long press on one of the list items,CAB show up with a button!i can use this button to select all items!and to deselct selected items!

Comment: so what's your question? Give more info on what it means for a list item to be _selected_.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Jquery and dropdown having `multiple` attribute

```
$('#selectall').click(function() {
    $('select#studentremain option').attr("selected","selected");
});   

$('#deselectall').click(function() {
   $('select#studentremain option').removeAttr("selected");
});
```

Two buttons are

```
<button type='button' id='selectall'>Select All</button>
<button type='button' id='deselectall'>De-Select All</button>
```

If you have list like this

```
<ul id="mylist">
<li>Element 1</li>
<li>Element 2</li>
<li>Element 3</li>
<li>Element 4</li>
<li>Element 5</li>
<li>Element 6</li>
</ul>
```

Then use this code

```
$('#mylist').on('click', 'li', function () {
if ($(this).hasClass('selected'))
{
    $(this).removeClass('selected');
    $('#mylist li').removeClass('not-selected');        
}
else
{
    $('#mylist li').removeClass('selected').addClass('not-selected');
    $(this).removeClass('not-selected').addClass('selected');
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using checkboxes to select item. The code I wrote below may be helpful

Write a method to check all your items are selected or not.

```
public boolean checkSelectedItems(){

     if(checkBox1.isChecked() && checkBox2.isChecked() && checkBox3.isChecked()){
        return true;
     }

     return false;

}
```

then set an onClickListener to your Button. In This example, this button checks if all items are checked or  all of them are not checked. If checked deselect all, otherwise select all of them. You can modify the code according to your app.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

              if(checkSelectedItems()){
                  //Deselect all items
                  checkBox1.setChecked(false);
                  checkBox2.setChecked(false);
                  checkBox3.setChecked(false);
              }else{
                  //Select all items
                  checkBox1.setChecked(true);
                  checkBox2.setChecked(true);
                  checkBox3.setChecked(true);
              }

        }
});
```

EDIT:
You need to change your for loop into this. Otherwise you all set your items false then set true again

```
for (int i = 0; i < listView.getCount(); ++i) {
  if (checkSelectedItems()){

      listView.setItemChecked(i, false);}
  else{

      listView.setItemChecked(i, true);
  }

}
```

Comment: cause I have no chechbox in my program i change ur code to above,but only select all worked !

Comment: :i try that but it didn't do anything,no select all and no deselect :|